# Flutter: How to return data without use button?

Tags: google-maps, flutter

How to return data without not clicking button?

I just want to use Image that `takesnapshot` of `GoogleMapController`, not showing `GoogleMap`.

But in example of `takesnapshot` they use button.

this is example.

```
const CameraPosition _kInitialPosition =
    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211), zoom: 11.0);

class SnapshotPage extends GoogleMapExampleAppPage {
  SnapshotPage()
      : super(const Icon(Icons.camera_alt), 'Take a snapshot of the map');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _SnapshotBody();
  }
}

class _SnapshotBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SnapshotBodyState createState() => _SnapshotBodyState();
}

class _SnapshotBodyState extends State<_SnapshotBody> {
  GoogleMapController _mapController;
  Uint8List _imageBytes;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 180,
            child: GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: _kInitialPosition,
            ),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Take a snapshot'),
            onPressed: () async {
              final imageBytes = await _mapController?.takeSnapshot();
              setState(() {
                _imageBytes = imageBytes;
              });
            },
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey[50]),
            height: 180,
            child: _imageBytes != null ? Image.memory(_imageBytes) : null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _mapController = controller;
  }
}
```

Is there any idea in here?

Comment: I want to show the image on the screen.

Comment: then how to process `GoogleMap`? I don't want to show it just want to show `takeSnapshot()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to try this in `initState(){}` , just create a method, and call in initState. For Example;

```
Future<CorrectDataType> _yourMethod() async {
              final imageBytes = await _mapController?.takeSnapshot();
              setState(() {
                _imageBytes = imageBytes;
       });
}
@override
initState(){
  _yourMethod();
  super.initState();
}
```

Think about of my answer, i hope you will find your way!